# 他们俩的性格差不多,挺像双胞胎一样: Can we use 挺 in this manner?

Tags: sentence-structure, writing-critique

I am trying to construct a sentence and I would like to know if this correct form of writing.

> 他们俩的性格差不多,挺像双胞胎一样.

Is this sentence alright? Can we use 挺 in this manner?

Answer (score 4):

'挺像 X' means  'quite like X'

'像 X 一样' means 'as same as X'

Either "他们俩的性格差不多, 挺像双胞胎的."  or  "他们俩的性格差不多, 就像双胞胎一样". would make better sentence

*就 implies 'exactly'. It is a more suitable adverb for 一样 (the same) than  挺 (quite)*

Note:

"他们俩的性格差不多" is grammatically correct , but logically, personality has nothing to do with being twin or not.

Comment: "挺": "quite", or "fairly"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need 一样:

他们俩的性格差不多，挺像双胞胎。

Comment: Yeah, 一样 is redundant as 挺像 already expressed a similar idea.